# This sorting array code cause the last element dissapear

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So, I tried to make an array using input first, then sorting it out from smallest to biggest, then display the array to monitor.

So I come up with this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pancakeSort(int sortArray[], int sortSize);

int main()
{
    // Input The Array Element Value
    int pancake[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Person " << i+1 << " eat pancakes = ";
        cin >> pancake[i];

}

// call pancake sorting function
pancakeSort(pancake, 10);

}



void pancakeSort(int sortArray[], int sortSize)
    {
        int length = 10;
        int temp;
        int stop = 10;

    // this is where the array get sorting out from smallest to biggest number
    for(int counter = length-1; counter>=0; counter--)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<stop; j++)
        {
            if(sortArray[j]>sortArray[j+1])
            {
                temp = sortArray[j+1];
                sortArray[j+1] = sortArray[j];
                sortArray[j]=temp;
            }

        }

        stop--;
    }



    // after that, the array get display here
    for(int x=0; x<sortSize; x++)
    {
        cout << sortArray[x] << " ";
    }


}
```

but the output is weird :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2aOf.jpg)

the function is successfully sorting the array from smallest to biggest,
but there is 2 weird things :
1. The biggest value element (which is 96  from what I input and it's the 10th element after got sorted out), disappear from the display.
2. For some reason, there is value 10 , which I didn't input on the array.


So, what happened?

Comment: Look at you inner loop's  if(sortArray[j]>sortArray[j+1])! what happens when j = 9, your index would go out of max index!

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
for(int j=0; j<stop; j++)
{
    if(sortArray[j]>sortArray[j+1])
    {
        temp = sortArray[j+1];
        sortArray[j+1] = sortArray[j];
        sortArray[j]=temp;
    }
}
```

`stop` is the length of the array, and you are iterating through values of `j = 0 to stop - 1`. When `j` reaches `stop - 1`, the next element that is `j+1` becomes `stop` (10 in this case). But since your array has a length of 10, `sortArray[10]` is not part of the array, but is referring to some other object in memory which is usually a garbage value. The garbage value is 10 in this case. When you swap `sortArray[10] and sortArray[9]`, the garbage value becomes part of the array and the value at index 9 leaves the array. This keeps on happening till the outer loop ends.

The end result is that unless the garbage value < largest element in the array, the garbage value is pushed in the array and the greatest value of the array is put at `sortArray[10]` which is not part of the array. If the garbage value is greater than all the values of the array, it'll be found at `sortArray[10]` which is again not part of the array and your code will return the desired result.

Essentially, what you are doing is giving the function an array of 10 (or `stop`) elements, but the function is actually working with an array of 11 (or `stop + 1`) elements, with the last element being a garbage value. The simple fix is to change the conditional of the loop to `j < stop - 1`.

Note that if you had written this code in a managed (or a comparatively higher level) language like Java or C#, it would have raised an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Man, I thought the garbage value would be -1 or random,

Comment: Your final comment is rather irrelevant since C++ also provides bounds-checked, exception-throwing indices in the form of `.at(index)` for STL containers including `std::array`, which is nearly universally recommended over the bare array it encapsulates. The fact that users aren't _required_ to use bounds-checked indices is a good thing, not bad; for everyone else, there's `.at()`.

Comment: @underscore_d That's why I said "Note that if you had written **this** code..." And nowhere did I say that no bounds checking by default is bad. I just stated that the code in its state would have raised an Exception in a managed language *because such an operation shouldn't be performed.* I don't intend to bring down C++, it's just to make my point clear.

Comment: Cool! I just wanted to emphasise that safe indexing is supported by standard containers and therefore isn't some missing feature of C++ compared to other languages. Not you, but other commenters tend to overlook/ignore these options and bash C++ for its supposed omission. Of course you're correct that, unlike others, we must deliberate tell C++ we want bounds-checking; its heritage means unchecked is the default.

Answer (score 0):

At index 9, `j+1` is out of bounds. So to fix this, you only need to check till index 8

```
for(int counter = length-1; counter>=0; counter--)
{
    for(int j=0; j<stop-1; j++)
    {
        if(sortArray[j]>sortArray[j+1])
        {
            temp = sortArray[j+1];
            sortArray[j+1] = sortArray[j];
            sortArray[j]=temp;
        }

    }

    stop--;
}
```

Look carefully at the inner loop condition `j<stop-1`